# How to change DbEntry settings at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I want to change the DB string connection I have stored in Web.config file depending on where is run the application.

I know how to read but, do anybody have an idea how to to change it?

Comment: You can change the connection string in web.config by opening in notepad, if you are trying to change it in hosting server.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to configure DbEntry at runtime (programatically).

Answer (score 0):

http://geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2005/10/09/56457.aspx

Third link to come up on a [BING search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=writing%20to%20web.config&form=CMDTDF&pc=CMDTDF&src=IE-SearchBox).

```
    private void GetConfigSettings() 
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath("Web.config"); 
        string newConnectionString = @"(Your connection string here)"; 

        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
        xDoc.Load(path); 

        XmlNodeList nodeList = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("appSettings"); 

        XmlNodeList nodeAppSettings = nodeList[0].ChildNodes; 

        XmlAttributeCollection xmlAttCollection = nodeAppSettings[0].Attributes;
        xmlAttCollection[0].InnerXml = txtKey.Text; // for key attribute
        xmlAttCollection[1].InnerXml = newConnectionString; // for value attribute

        xDoc.Save(path); // saves the web.config file         

    }
```

Comment: In other words: Is there another way (programatically) to configure DbEntry without using Web.config file?

Answer (score 0):

*New answer based on your comment on my original answer*

You can use the String.Replace function.  The ConnectionString is just a string.

```
string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
connectionString = connectionString.Replace("TextToReplace", "ReplacementText");
```

so assuming your connection string is

```
"Data Source=LiveDbServer;Initial Catalog=MyDataBase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=someUserId;Password=yourPassword"
```

You could use the following logic

```
if(System.Environment.ServerName == "MyTestServer")
{
   connectionString = connectionString.Replace("LiveDbServer", "TestDbServer");
}
```

---

*The following is just based on a guess as to why you might want to change connectionstrings at run-time based on which server the app is running on*

ALTHOUGH (added bonus idea) **if your goal is to always have your test web server point to your test DB server and your live web server point to your live DB server**, an easier method is to [edit the HOSTS file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file).  (I'm sure there are other options, but that was a simple enough hack for us, and it works with database connections, web service references, etc.)

Simply set up the hosts file on the test machine so that it maps "MyLiveDbServer" to the ipaddress of "MyTestDbServer", and viola - your apps will point to the test server without any extra code or configuration, automatically, and for all time.

Answer (score 0):

I used to load the connection string into the Application object (for better or worse) in the Application_Start event of global.asax.

Then, I get the option of checking which server I'm running on and loading that connection string into the Application object, rhather than relying on just a single entry in web.config.

Example:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="testservername" connectionString="..." providerName="..."/>
  <add name="prodservername" connectionString="..." providerName="..."/>
  <add name="localhost"      connectionString="..." providerName="..."/>
</connectionStrings>
```

...in global.asax:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" %>
...
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  Application("cn") = ConnectionStrings(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"))
End Sub
```

So then, every time I *would have* used `ConnectionStrings("cn")`, I will instead use `Application("cn")`.

Check to see what HTTP_HOST gives you on each server and name your connection strings accordingly.

Alternately, you could just use `ConnectionStrings(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"))` all over instead of storing the whole string in Application.

Another option would be to just store the host name in the Application variable to pass to `ConnectionStrings` any time you need it.